# Why is both identical sentence's METEOR score used in Machine Translation not equals to one?

Tags: nlp, metrics, machine-translation

I have both identical sentences. But METEOR Score is not 1 it's 0.99.

Here's the code:  `score1 = nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(sentence1,sentence2)`

Comment: Can you clarify which meteor you are talking about? Please have a look at the meteor tag you used and make sure it's the right one. I have suspicion it's not. If it is, please elaborate, because as it stands I think your question is lacking detail.

Comment: I'm talking about the METEOR used for machine translation.
Here's the code:  score1 = nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score(sentence1,sentence2)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a sort of rounding error in computing the chunking penalty. It says into how many incoherent chunks the sentence must have been split to get the alignment between the reference and the hypothesis. Its purpose is to penalize hypothesis sentences that contain correct words and phrases, but in a very different order than in the reference.

See the [paper introducing METEOR](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ealavie/METEOR/pdf/meteor-1.5.pdf), Section 2:

[image]

If you get rid of the penalty by setting `gamma` to zero, you will always get 1.0 for identical sentence:

```py
import nltk
sentence = "This is a very long sentence."

nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score([sentence], sentence, gamma=1)
# returns 0.9953703703703703

nltk.translate.meteor_score.meteor_score([sentence], sentence, gamma=0)
# returns 1.0
```